# javascript getElementByTagName

Tags: javascript, variables

The question is to create a function `showLink()` which has a variable `sIndx` that points to  the index of the selected option in the current selection list.

```
   <select name="executive" id="executive" class="optionLinks">
      <option value="#">Select a Web site</option
      <option value="http://www.whitehouse.gov">The White House</option>
      <option value="http://www.usda.gov">Department of Agriculture</option>             
   </select>
   <select name="legislative" id="legislative" class="optionLinks">
      <option value="#">Select a Web site</option>
      <option value="http://www.house.gov">House Web Site</option>
      <option value="http://www.house.gov/house  </option>
      <option value="http://clerk.house.gov/">Clerk of the House</option>     
   </select>
   <select name="judicial" id="judicial" class="optionLinks">
      <option value="#">Select a Web site</option>
      <option value="http://www.uscourts.gov">U.S. Courts</option>
      <option value="http://www.uscourts.gov/supremecourt.html">U.S.Supreme              </select>
```

My answer:

```
function Link()  {   
   sIndex = document.getElementByTagName("select")[this.select].options[selectedIndex];
   location.href = sindex.value;
}
```

The webpage is not loading, I still see the options clicked, any help?

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped the function name, it should be `document.getElementsByTagName` (plural "Elements").

The function `document.getElementsByTagName("select")` will return an array of `select` objects. To get the right object, you would need to know its correct index in the array. You are using `this.select` for that, make sure to check it has the right value.

Even if that works, I don't see where you defined the `selectedIndex` variable in your code. Maybe you meant something like this:

```
function Link() {
   var obj = document.getElementByTagName("select")[this.select];
                                   // assuming this ^^^^^^^^^^^ is the right index
   var item = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex];
   location.href = item.value;
}
```

There is also a typo in your HTML, in `#legislative` you did not close a `value` attribute correctly which might cause problems.